# MySQL_Query not working for building a Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to use this code to make my install file, carry out a SQL Command within a function.

Here is the code:

```
      private function buildDB() {
  $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
id          bigint(20),
md5_id      VARCHAR(200),
created     VARCHAR(100),
full_name   tinytext,
user_name   varchar(200),
user_email  varchar(220),
user_level  tinyint(4),
pwd         varchar(220),
address     text,
country     varchar(200),
tel         varchar(200),
fax         varchar(200),
website     text,
date        date,
users_ip    varchar(200),
approved    int(1),
activation_code int(10),
banned      int(1),
ckey        varchar(220),
ctime       varchar(220),
)
MySQL_QUERY;

    return mysql_query($sql) or die("failed because of the following error: " . mysql_error());


  }
```

Unfortunately its coming up with the following error

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 22
```

But MySQL is on the latest version and i can not work it out at the moment, is there something i'm missing.

Line 22 of the file is:

```
   private function buildDB() {
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure the last `,` isn't supposed to be there

Comment: Thank you!! What a Silly Mistake. Can't believe i missed that. Working now.